# MySQL sub-SELECT from same table

Tags: mysql

This is oversimplified for the purpose of this question, but suppose I have an `INVENTORY` table with the following columns: `SKU`, `DATE`, `QUANTITY`.  I want to select all of the columns where the `QUANTITY` from the day previous is less than the `QUANTITY` for any day.  How do you write a `SELECT` query with a sub `SELECT` on the same table?

Or, if anyone knows what to call this kind of query so I can do more research on my own that would be helpful.  (ie., Is this a recursive query?)

Comment: Your result set is empty, because a quantity can't be less than the minimum of a set of which it is a member...

Comment: @KeithRandall -- why not?  If I sold zero phones yesterday, but 10 phones on each other day before that, that's a minimum quantity that he wants to select.

Comment: @beemerGuy.net: I'm being pedantic, but if you sold 10 phones one day and 0 phones the other, then the minimum quantity for *any day* is 0.  My comment was something of a joke, in that the OP intended to say "any day before the previous day", not just "any day" (which includes the previous day).

Comment: @KeithRandall -- that **is** pedantic.  Contextually, I'm sure he meant "any _other_ day".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is a good start for you (if I understand your schema correctly).
In English, this will select all SKU's whose quantities yesterday are less than the minimum quantity from all previous days for the same SKU.

```
SELECT 
    SKU, 
    Quantity

FROM 
    INVENTORY inv

WHERE
    inv.DATE = GETDATE() - 1
    AND inv.QUANTITY < (SELECT MIN(prev_inv.QUANTITY) 
                        FROM INVENTORY prev_inv
                        WHERE 
                            prev_inv.DATE < GETDATE() - 1 
                            AND prev_inv.SKU = inv.SKU
                       )
```

Comment: This is helpful, I didn't think to use table aliases.  I'm not sure if you are willing to correct this, but I need the sku, quantity, and date where the quantity of the immediate day before was less.

Comment: wait.... you want to compare it to the **previous** day?  Or **any** previous day?  @KeithRandall deserves credit for being pedantic after all =)

Comment: I found that a query like this takes long to execute (>11 secs in my case). Any way to make it faster?

Answer (score 3):

You can join a table to its self for this sort of thing. The exact syntax probably isn't right for the date math and if you have multiple records per day you might want to do some GROUPing, but I hope you get the idea.

```
SELECT i1.*
FROM INVENTORY AS i1
JOIN INVENTORY AS i2 ON i2.DATE = i1.DATE + 1
WHERE i1.QUANTITY > i2.QUANTITY
```

Comment: you sir are an absolute gentleman and a scholar, this makes so much sense and is very readable and im 10 years too late but still